# React/Express could not load the image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I'am craet React/Express app and i have an problem with images. They don't show up - "could not load the image".

CSS styles loads, but image not loads.

I suspect, problem on server side with static files.

Express code:

```
import express from 'express';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/server';
import { indexTemplate } from './indexTemplate';
import App from "../App";

const app = express();

app.use('/static', express.static('./dist/client'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(
    indexTemplate(ReactDOM.renderToString(App()),)
  );
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started, on http://localhost:3000');
});
```

CSS code where i'am use image as background:

```
.main {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: url("../../static/img1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

My client webpack config:

```
const path = require( 'path' );
const { HotModuleReplacementPlugin } = require( 'webpack' );
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require( 'clean-webpack-plugin' );

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const IS_DEV = NODE_ENV === 'development';
const IS_PROD = NODE_ENV === 'production';
const GLOBAL_CSS_REGEXP = /\.global\.css$/;

function setupDevtool() {
  if ( IS_DEV ) {
    return 'eval';
  }

  if ( IS_PROD ) {
    return false;
  }
}

module.exports = {
  mode: NODE_ENV ? NODE_ENV : 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json' ],
    alias: {
      'react-dom': 'react-dom',
    }
  },
  entry: [
    path.resolve( __dirname, '../src/client/index.jsx' ),
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=http://localhost:3001/static/__webpack_hmr',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, '../dist/client' ),
    filename: 'client.js',
    publicPath: '/static/',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[tj]sx?$/,
        use: [ 'ts-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                mode: 'local',
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: GLOBAL_CSS_REGEXP
      },
      {
        test: GLOBAL_CSS_REGEXP,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: setupDevtool(),
  plugins: IS_DEV
    ? [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
      new HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    ]
    : [],
};
```

My server webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const GLOBAL_CSS_REGEXP = /\.global\.css$/;


module.exports = {
  target: "node",
  mode: NODE_ENV ?? "development",
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "../src/server/server.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist/server"),
    filename: "server.js",
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[tj]sx?$/,
        use: [ 'ts-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                mode: 'local',
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: GLOBAL_CSS_REGEXP
      },
      {
        test: GLOBAL_CSS_REGEXP,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|gif|png|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 10000
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This path is relative to the location of the CSS file, not the location of the HTML file that includes the CSS. So, if your CSS file is in a directory that is not at the root level of your application, the relative path may not be correct.

To fix this, you can use an absolute path to the image file, like this:

```
.main {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: url("/static/img1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

This path is relative to the root of your application, so it should work regardless of where your CSS file is located. Note the leading `/` in the path, which indicates that it is an absolute path.

Try updating your CSS with this absolute path and see if the image loads correctly.